# Jquery Autocomplete Search with Ajax Request as sourcedata

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jquery-ui-autocomplete

**What I want to do:**

I want to do a input text field with a jquery autocomplete function which gets the source data from a cross-domain curl request. The result should be exactly like this example (CSS not important here): http://abload.de/img/jquerydblf5.png (So I actually want to show additional infos which I get from the curl Request). The URL to get the source data is `http://www.futhead.com/15/players/search/quick/?term=` and in the end I add those letters which are currently typed in at my input field (for example "Ronaldo").

At the moment I only tried to perform the searchrequest without showing all infosin the dropdown as shown in the screen above. I only want to see which playernames I actually got back by the curl request. Later I will try to add more information for the dropdown. Maybe you guys can help me as well with this as well (I think its called custom renderItem ??).

**This is what I've tried:**

```
<script>
 $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'playerscraper.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data: function () { 
                return $("#results").val() 
            },
            success: function (data) {
                // I have no idea what this response and map is good for
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.label,
                        id: item.value,
                    };
                }));
            },
        });
    }
});
</script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

My playerscraper.php is performing the curl request and actually returns a array (tested with echo):

```
$term = $_GET['term'];
$curlRequest = new CurlRequest(); 
$result = $curlRequest->get('http://www.futhead.com/15/players/search/quick/?term=' . $searchterm);
$players = array();

return json_encode($result);
```

**My problem:**

I have no idea how to do the source part for the autocomplete function this way, that I get the right results from the ajax request with my searchterm from the input field. When I type in something in the input field, nothing happens (the function which defines the source is getting called - tested with an alert).

**First try to fix the problem with your help (current Code):**

```
<script>
 $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'playerscraper.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data: function () {
                term: request.term
            },
            success: function (data) {
                // I have no idea what this response and map is good for
                response($.map(data, function(item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.full_name,
                        value: item.player_id
                    };
                }));
            },
        });
    },
    minLength: 3,
    delay: 500
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you hitting `playerscraper.php` rather han `http://www.futhead.com/15/players/search/quick/?term=`..?

Comment: BTW how does the `data` in ajax success callback look like..?

Comment: Because I need to get this data from futhead via a Curl Request because of the allow origin rule there. Its not my own page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON is in a format which is incompatible with what autocomplete widget expects. This is where the `$.map` comes into play. You use this function to convert the JSON to desired format. Begin by returning a `{label: "display name", value: "some id"}` pairs like this:

```
response($.map(data, function(item) {
    return {
        label: item.full_name,
        value: item.player_id
    };
}));
```

Notes:

1. You should send content type header with your JSON:

> ```
> header("Content-Type: application/json");
> echo $result;
> ```

2. You should use `request.term` instead of input element value for the `data` parameter like this:

> ```
> data: { term: request.term }
> ```

3. You should set higher `delay` and `minLength` values to reduce number of JSON requests:

> ```
> delay: 500,
> minLength: 3,
> ```

4. There are some undefined variables in your PHP script. Fix. Make sure that you `echo` the JSON instead of `return`ing it. The remote server sends JSON so there is no need to json encode it again.

> ```
> $term = $_GET['term'];
> $result = file_get_contents('http://www.futhead.com/15/players/search/quick/?term=' . $term);
> header("Content-Type: application/json");
> echo $result;
> ```

5. Always check your PHP scripts for issues by opening directly in browser. Always look at browser JavaScript console to look for JavaScript errors and warnings.

Comment: Hi, I read your comment and tried to update my current code, but it still doesn't work. I updated the current javascript part into the thread.

Comment: Ignore previous comment, there are still issues in your JavaScript (use `data: { term: request.term }` instead of `data: function() {}`) and your PHP script. See revised answer.

Comment: Thanks for your effort for this, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Few things are looking wrong in in jQuery code

1. You have used `$_GET['term']` in server side code but not passed `term` in ajax request query string
    Need to fix as

   > data: {term: request.term}
2. extra comman(`,`) in code, it will create issue in IE browsers

   > response($.map(data, function (item) {
   >                       return {
   >                           label: item.label,
   >                           id: item.value
   >                       };
   >                   }));

Comment: Hi, I read your comment and tried to update my current code, but it still doesn't work. I updated the current javascript part into the thread.

Comment: `Delay` option should in small case `delay` any error in firebug console?

Comment: Changed it, no difference. No unfortunately no error in the console. I have the guess that the result of the playerscraper.php ajax request is empty. How can I check for this and how should I debug it step by step so I can see what actually works and what doesn't ?

Comment: for debug ajax response: use firefox browser and install `firebug` addon then open firebug by `f12` key and type in `#tag` input element.. hope it would be helpful